# Hibernate Search Help

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Getting error when adding  PhoneticAnalyzer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the library/jar that contains **PhoneticAnalyzer** in your classpath. You can download that library from [here](http://www.tangentum.biz/en/products/phonetix/) and add it to your classpath

Comment: Yes, that's was the problem, but do u know how to use MultiFieldQueryParser with PhoneticAnalyzer

Comment: @Noor - nope I am not aware of it. See if this link helps you https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1003107